# Paginate big array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, pagination, electron

I have a js array that will cause some issue to my electron app due to it's size, it will contain about 53000 objects. To avoid performances issues, how I can split it when data are loaded on application start? at the moment I'm getting the data from ad odbc access file and pushing it to an array on the front-end using vuejs.

background.js

```js
ipcMain.on('init', (event, ...args) => {
    let suppliersData = false
    let clientsData = false
    suppliersdb.query('SELECT * FROM FANFOR0F_1')
        .then( (results) => {
            console.log(results.length)
            //
            suppliersData = true
            //result.NEMA = result.NEMA.replace('§', '@')
            event.sender.send('suppliersData', results)            
        }).catch( e => { 
            console.log(e) 
            event.sender.send('databaseUpdateError', e)
        })
    clientsdb.query('SELECT * FROM PDECON0F_1')
        .then( (results) => {
            console.log(results.length)
            clientsData = true
            event.sender.send('clientsData', results)
        }).catch( e => {
            console.log(e)
            event.sender.send('databaseUpdateError', e)
        })
    //
    if( suppliersData && clientsData ){
        event.sender.send('databaseUpdateCompleted')
    }
})
```

vue frontend-loading time `mounted()` hook

```
        window.ipcRenderer.send('init')
        window.ipcRenderer.receive('suppliersData', (data) => {
            this.suppliersDataAvailable = true
            this.store.suppliers = data
        })
        window.ipcRenderer.receive('clientsData', (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            this.clientsDataAvailable = true
            this.store.clients = data
        })
```

My idea is to split it into different pages or lazyload the content when page is scrolled, I'm implementing rxdb to have a local copy of the data and decrease loading time on application startup. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found an easier solution that involves .slice() method:

```
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
const arrays = [];
const arraysLengths = 4;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i=i+arraysLengths) {
    arrays.push(array.slice(i,i+arraysLengths));
    
};
console.log(arrays);
```

everything works the same. Except you don't need that temporary array anymore.

Comment: I will test your code and let you know. Enjoy the community!

Comment: Just a consideration, I will need to loop the array in vuejs when needed, do you know a way to implement pagination if I split the array in this way?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know how to paginate things. I’m new in JavaScript. I know only vanilla JavaScript stuff.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not difficult. I'm testing your suggested solution, but at the moment seems not working at all in vue. I'll let you know anyway

Comment: It worked fine. I have now my arrays paginated. I will start from this point to add pagination in my vue electron app. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution:

```
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
//main array that you want to split
const arrays = [];
//small arrays
const arraysLengths = 4;
//elements in one array
let array1 = [] 
//temporary array


for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i=i+arraysLengths) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arraysLengths; j++) {
        if ((i+j) <= array.length - 1) {
            array1.push(array[i+j])
        }

    };
    //this is the code that splits arrays

arrays.push(array1);
array1=[]
//transfer arrays into another array
};
console.log(arrays)  //show result
```

You can insert any natural number in arrayLengths and it will work.
You can find all the arrays in arrays array

Comment: Hello, welcome on stackoverflow. I will try your suggestion. At the moment I'm using the `Array.slice()` function to have a copy of the original array that is assigned to a dedicated variable in vue app. My idea is to implement an infinite scroll so the slice will be modified everytime needed, but I'm not sure if this will work as expected